# Check if the file exist only by the file name (without the extension)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This works just fine

```
if [[ -e img.png ]]
then
     echo "exist"
else
     echo "doesn't exist"
fi
```

but what if I know that there might be imgage with name img but I do not know if the file is .jpg , .gif , .jpeg , .tff and so on.

I do not care what is the extension I just want to know if there is a file with name 'img'

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
files=$(ls img.* 2> /dev/null | wc -l)
if [ "$files" != "0" ]
then
echo "exist"
else
echo "doesn't exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following scripts

```
files=`ls img.* 2>/dev/null`
if [ "$files" -a ${#files[@]} ]; then
    echo "exist"
else
    echo "doesn't exist"
fi
```

In this snippet, you use `ls img.*` to list all the files in current working directory whose name match the pattern `img.*`.
The result is stored into an array named `files`.
Then check size of the array to determine whether required files exist.

See [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/finding-bash-shell-array-length-elements/) for how to get length of the array.

Comment: Care to explain the bash syntax you used there?

Comment: What if there are no img.* files?

Comment: @codaddict Thanks for your comment, update my answer to check empty case :).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job:

```
if [[ $(ls img.*) ]]; then
  echo "file exist";
else
  echo "file does not exist";
fi
```

I recommend to have a look at bash's pattern matching:
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_03.html

Answer (score 0):

Without any external command:

```
$ for i in img.*
> do
>  [ -f $i ] && echo exist || echo not exist
>  break
> done
```

Check if any file is present. If present print exist , else not exist, and break immediately. The "-f" check is needed because if no files are present, still the loop runs once with i as "img.*" itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=( img.* )
if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then
    echo "there are no 'img' files"
fi
```

If you don't use `nullglob` then, if there are no such files, the array will have 1 element, the literal string "img.*".